# Перебор дат на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, выборка

коллеги.Есть квота доставок в день. Код ниже выбирает всю за дату, указанную в post-запросе. но только за одну. Как сделать, чтобы выбирал По выбранным датам в течение месяца?

```
for i in  range(10):
    r = requests.post(url + '/.../.../',
                        json={"fias": fias_code, "code": "issue_card",
                            "date": '2019-11-14'})
```

Comment: В показанном коде присвоение находится за пределами (пустого) цикла.

Comment: @Akina в питоне не может быть пустого цикла, выбрасывается IndentationError.

Comment: @Эникейщик Может, не силён. Но, ЕМНИП, код в питоне ident-compatible, так что тело цикла должно быть смещено относительно оператора, его открывающего. Я уж и не говорю о том, что переменная-итератор в планируемом коде тела цикла просто не используется... хотя фиг знает, что там на стороне сервера.

Comment: @Эникейщик  Коллеги. Этот код рабочий. Можно чуть более к теме)

Comment: В вопросе - не рабочий. Не хватает отступов.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться встроенными в Python батарейками: [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.timedelta), [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.date.strftime)

```
>>> import time
>>> from datetime import date
>>> today = date.today()
>>> today
datetime.date(2019, 10, 16)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2019-10-16'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> today + timedelta(days=1)
datetime.date(2019, 10, 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот как-то так. Заработало.

```
def cvota(url, fias_code):
    dates = ['2019-10-18', '2019-10-19']

    for dateIndex in range(len(dates)):
        for count in range(5):
            r = requests.post(url + '/.../.../.../',
                                json={"fias": fias_code, "code": "issue_card", "date": dates[dateIndex]})
            kvota = r.text
            print(kvota)
            print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Можно проще: `for dateIndex in range(len(dates)):` -> `for date in dates:` и `json={"fias": fias_code, "code": "issue_card", "date": date})`